# Elasticsearch date Invalid format too short

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch model with a field `starts_at` with the mapping

```
"starts_at": {
               "type": "date",
               "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
             }
```

When I try to enter `2018-07-29T13:00:00Z`, I get the error `Invalid format: \"2018-07-29\" is too short"`

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [starts_at]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [starts_at]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"2018-07-29\" is too short"}},"status":400}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just wondering about `2018-07-29T13:00:00Z`. What is the meaning of `Z` here?
It should be a time zone I think.

Comment: so the format with the `Z` is a `UTC` format but I also get the same error if I try to enter `2018-07-29T08:00:00-05:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce it:

```
DELETE test 
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "starts_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST test/_doc
{
  "starts_at": "2018-07-29T08:00:00-05:00"
}
```

This works well...

Comment: So it turns out that some is up with the ruby gem that persist the object to the ES index. when I used the a different gem, it worked